# Use signals and slots in console application?

Tags: c++, qt, console-application, signals-slots

In my project, I need to download a 1.5MB file from a server. I was able to achieve this in my GUI application like this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* m_NetworkMngr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("someurl.com")));
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    QUrl aUrl("someurl.com");
    QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

    QFile file(aPathInClient+"\\"+fileInfo.fileName());//aPathInClient is predefined
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());
    delete reply;
```

I am getting the following error:

'connect' function does not take four arguments.

How can I modify the signals and slots to work in my console application?

Comment: You know you can use Qt in non-GUI (i.e. console) applications as well? Complete with signals and slots and everything.

Comment: -_- o really? Wow well don't I feel stupid. Then do you know why I get an error saying too many arguments? This is in reference to "connect"

Comment: @mc360pro Because you are sending too many arguments to "connect"? Anyway Joachim is right, you can use Qt with console applications, I've done it, and it works.

Comment: Is it not the same as in a gui? I currently have 4 arguments.

Comment: @mc360pro Why don't you edit your question, title and everything, to ask about that error instead? Describe it, post 3-4 lines of the code around the error, and we'll help you. Your question as it currently stands is pointless, it rests on a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your code is correct with regards to establishing signal/slot connection, however compiler seems to be confused because of the `connect()` function name and cannot resolve it properly: whether it is `QObject::connect()` that takes at least 4 arguments, or it is another function with the same name, but different signature. I would suggest to try to explicitly tell compiler which function to use, i.e.:

```
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```